# Getting kubectl config use-context error when trying to switch context

Tags: config, kubectl

When I am trying to switch kubectl configuration using "**kubectl config use-context new-context**" where new-context is my desired context, I am getting the following error on my Mac machine:

**error: open some-context.lock: file exists**

where **some-context** is another kubectl configuration. However, some-context is not the active context. I see the same error when try "**kubectl config set-context new-context**" as well.

How can I fix the issue? I am using MacOS Mojava, version: 10.14.6.

Comment: Can you locate the `.lock` file and delete it? You can use `find ~ -name some-context.lock` to find it.

Comment: @KFC_ I could not find that file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was with my KUBECONFIG environment variable. It had duplicate entries for **some-context** . After removing the duplicate entry, it works as expected.

Comment: ```export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config:<other-config-file>``` includes /.kube at the root directory, where it's very likely the user doesn't have permission. 

```export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:<other config files>``` should work!

Answer (score 8):

Deleting the `~/.kube/config.lock` worked for me when I had the same issue, but the file was present for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got fixed after deleting the config.lock file from the C:\Users<user-id>.kube folder from windows.